# Get json objects from server

Tags: json, angular

I am trying to get a JSON object API from server and my json start with objects and l am not familiar with Json response start with objects immediately .

[Json url](https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=a478c3ea711f4345800c4d3e3434a804)

```
{
  "ABQ": {
    "airport": {
      "name": "Albuquerque International Airport",
      "code": {
        "iata": "ABQ",
        "icao": "KABQ"
      }
    }
  },
  "ACE": {
    "airport": {
      "name": "Lanzarote Airport",
      "code": {
        "iata": "ACE",
        "icao": "GCRR"
      }
    }
  },
  "ADB": {
    "airport": {
      "name": "Izmir Adnan Menderes International Airport",
      "code": {
        "iata": "ADB",
        "icao": "LTBJ"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My code :

```
 Data :any

    getData(){

        this.http.get("xxxxxxxx/", {}, {}).then(data =>{

        this.Data = JSON.parse(data.data)

        console.log(this.Data)

        })
      }
```

HTML

```
 <div class="ion-padding">

    {{Data.airport.name}}

  </div>
```

l got error

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'airport' of undefined at object.eval

how can l get the data json response ?

Comment: it seems that you trying to display data before promise resolved.
maybe <div ng-If="Data">{{Data.airport.name}}</div> will resolve issue

Comment: No Error shows ! , but l have empty page ?  and the data is exist in console @AlexeySemerenko

Comment: hmm maybe ng-if="Data !== undefined" will help?

Comment: Your resonse data is JSON object try `{{Data.ABQ.airport.name}}` or `{{Data.ACE.airport.name}}` or `{{Data.ADB.airport.name}}` and so on.

Comment: Are you sure it's AngularJS? Not Angular?

Comment: @SudhirOjha , l cant use ADB or ABQ because it change every time

Comment: ionic & Angular

Comment: or you can introduce local variable isDataReadyToDisplay and in "then()" set it to true after this.Data = JSON.parse(data.data). And in the view check this variable in ng-if (eg: <div ng-if="isDataReadyToDisplay">...)

Comment: Then the problem is you're rendering nested object properties before you get data from server as guys stated above, *ngIf should work for you. However, you should do smth with intermediate properties like `ADB`. You can't just ignore them

Comment: what do you get with `console.log(data)` ?

Comment: @SergeyMell l cant use ADB because those value are always change is

Comment: @AmadouBeye `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`

Comment: @AliGhassan if data comes like that which airport you want to show, there are 3 in your response.(I mean when it's dynamic how do you determine which one, do you want to loop through them?)

Comment: @RezaRahmati you can check my data json url [https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=a478c3ea711f4345800c4d3e3434a804]

Comment: @SergeyMell check out my url https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=a478c3ea711f4345800c4d3e3434a804

Comment: @AliGhassan, ok, but if your object looks like {a: {smthDynamic: {b: value} }} you can't fetch it like a.b just because intermediate value is dynamic and you don't know it. This won' work

Comment: @SergeyMell so what is best way to fetch all those data ? https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=a478c3ea711f4345800c4d3e3434a804

Comment: You can try this `<div *ngFor='let item of Data | keyvalue'>
   Name = {{Data[item.key].airport.name}}
</div>`

Comment: he is working now , thank you very much @SudhirOjha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems in your example:

1. You're trying to render the data before it was loaded. And as long as you're trying to get user attributes you get exceptions like `Cannot read property XXX of undefined`
2. You are ignoring intermediate properties of your data object.

There is more than one way to skin a cat and there are several possible solutions. One of them I've implemented in this example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zuqbry.

1. I'm using `async` filter to wait for the server response to be resolved

   ```
   <p *ngFor="let item of data | async">
     {{item.airport.name}}
   </p>
   ```
2. I'm iterating over Object keys in order to get all there 'dynamic keys' and fetch data from the data object

   ```
   this.data = http.get()
     .pipe(
       map(response => {
         const keys = Object.keys(response);
         return keys.map(key => response[key]);
       })
     );
   ```

   Please, note that `http` is an object of `CustomHttpService` that I've created to provide data from hardcoded file, however it works very similar to original `HttpClient`.

Comment: can you check this question please ? is simillier to my

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get what you mean in your comment

Comment: l mean check this question pls ,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56797773/how-to-iterate-objects-into-google-map/56797972

Comment: Sure, I'll do in a while

Comment: It seems your question is deleted. At least I get a 404 page error

Comment: l am sorry . this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56803700/loop-json-objects-keys-to-add-google-maps-data/56804490

Comment: my question is how l can inject those objects keys in google map ?